# How to create Gutenberg's pattern category automatically with custom post taxonomy terms?

Tags: block-editor

I’m trying to create pattern category form each custom post taxonomy term that is assigned to post in custom post type `ml_patterns_`. Actually I have 3 posts with different terms.

Code:

```
$patternsTerms = get_terms('ml_patternsCustomTaxonomy', array('hide_empty' => 0, 'parent' =>0)); 
    foreach($patternsTerms as $patternTerm):
    
      $slug = $patternTerm->slug;
      $name = $patternTerm->name;
    
      register_block_pattern_category(
          $slug,
            array(
              'label' => $name,
          )
        );
    
    endforeach;
```

the results is one pattern category `Uncategorized` which is event not created in this taxonomy. To test it I've tried this, on single page:

```
$patternsTerms = get_terms('ml_patternsCustomTaxonomy', array('hide_empty' => 0, 'parent' =>0)); 
foreach($patternsTerms as $patternTerm):

    $slug = $patternTerm->slug;
    $name = $patternTerm->name;

    echo $slug;
    echo '</br>';
    echo $name;
    echo '<hr>';

endforeach;
```

and here it’s works ok. Any idea? :)

Comment: Where are you running the first code? Make sure it's inside an `init` action's callback, so it's not running too early, if it's in your `functions.php` file. The `get_terms()` usually takes only a single input array argument, but this might still work the old way. Make sure you're not clashing with existing categories by using relevant namespace.

Comment: Yes, it's in `functions.php`. I've wrapped this code with `add_action('init', function() { // }` but no expected results.

Comment: Try e.g. registering categories manually there without get_terms() loop, and verify the bool output of register_block_pattern_category() is true

Comment: I'm also vary of uppercase letters in `ml_patternsCustomTaxonomy` and there's also a maximum number of taxonomy names letters, don't remember what it is now. But since you verified it, then it might work, but these are typical problems with various keys in WP :-).